# derivation of ratio distribution of two normals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given two distributions $Y$ and $X$ with joint probability density function $f(x,y)$, and letting $U=Y/X$, then I would write the cumulative distribution function of $u$ as:

\begin{equation}
P(U \le u) = P(Y \le uX | X > 0) + P(Y \le uX | X < 0)
\end{equation}

However, all texts write it as:

\begin{equation}
P(U \le u) = P(Y \le uX | X > 0) + P(Y \ge uX | X < 0)
\end{equation}

i.e. a difference in the 2nd term on the RHS. I realise this term is in the region of $X < 0$ and hence some rearrangement is required, but I cannot see how precisely how this is done.

Can someone please show this?

Comment: Multiplication by a negative number changes the direction of the inequality sign.

Comment: Doh! Thank you.